# How does rvalue reference work here?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, lvalue-to-rvalue

I am puzzled by the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x{};

    int&& rvx = static_cast<int&&>(x);
    ++rvx;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

The output of it is `1`. I don't understand how this works. The `static_cast` is supposed to cast the lvalue `x` into an xvalue, which is then assigned to `rvx`. Why does incrementing `rvx` lead to a change in `x`? Is this because the converted lvalue-to-rvalue is essentially sitting at the same memory location, but it is just considered now a rvalue? I was under the impression (which is probably false) that somehow the cast creates a temporary out of its argument.

Comment: I think you are mixed up about what *lvalue* and *rvalue* means.  Those are adjectives that describe an expression. They are not varieties of objects.

Comment: There is no internal state of an integer, besides it's value (There is nothing to move).

Comment: @MattMcNabb I was a bit sloppy on my wording, I know that objects are always lvalues (as they are named), but as I said was under the impression that the static_cast makes a copy.

Comment: no, objects are not lvalues. They're objects.  An lvalue is a category of expression.

Comment: @DieterLücking yes I know that writing `int x = std::move(y)` etc is non-sense. I was just confused with the cast.

Comment: @vsoftco Now I think you're confused between objects and variables.

Comment: @hvd, yes I am actually by the terminology

Comment: @vsoftco An object is a region of memory. There's also some bits about an object's type, but the important part, it's a region of memory. There's no notion of how you access that memory. It may be through a variable, or it may be through any other expression. The result of a succesful call to `malloc()` points to an object, or to a sequence of objects, even though there is no variable referring to those objects.

Comment: @hvd, ok, makes sense now. So basically `static_cast<int&&>(x)` is just an expression denoting an object that happens to have the share the same memory with `x`, which is then bound to the lvalue `rvx` of type rvalue reference, am I right?

Comment: @MattMcNabb It is a C++-standard term. [basic] A *variable* is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member or of an object. The variable’s name denotes the reference or object.

Comment: @vsoftco `static_cast<int&&>(x)` is not an object, it's an expression. An object is a region of storage, as hvd says.  Expressions may or may not denote objects.  Objects cannot share memory with other objects (except for sub-objects, e.g. array elements)

Comment: @hvd now that's a confusing sentence, I guess it is meant to be parsed as  (the declaration of a reference other than...) or ([the declaration] of an object)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Indeed. Both that it's confusing, and that that's how it should be parsed. :)

Comment: OK, so variables can share storage, and we would say that  `rvx` and `x` are both variables that denote the same object.

Comment: @vsoftco Pretty much. `static_cast<int&&>(x)` is an expression that refers to the same object that `x` refers to (not just a different object at the same memory location, but really the same object), and that object is bound to `rvx`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Indeed, that's a good way of putting it.

Comment: Ok, thanks all, I understand now what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An rvalue reference *can* bind to a temporary. This is what you'd get, for instance, if you write

```
int x{};
int&& rvx = +x;
```

But it doesn't *need* to bind to a temporary. By casting `x` to `int&&`, you've indicated to the compiler that that's okay too, that it may treat `x` as an rvalue to bind directly to the reference.

Answer (score 5):

rvalue reference is a reference. In this, it works just like any other reference.